# light.exe : error LGHT0199 : The WixLocalization element has an incorrect namespace of 'WixLocalization'

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

When I run the below command from the command line for the WIx installer after migrated from version 2.0 to 4.0:

```
E:\Source\TestProgram\builder>ant -v -f Build.xml -Dlabel =.001 install
```

I am getting the below error:

> [exec] light.exe : error LGHT0199 : The WixLocalization element has an
> incorrect namespace of 'WixLocalization'.  Please make the
> WixLocalization element look like the following: .
> [ant] Exiting E:\Source\TestProgram1.0.1English_installer.xml.

I want to know the root cause of the error?

I checked **`"TestProgram1.0.1English_Installer.wxs"`** file for "**`WixLocalization`**" but didn't find any thing.

Pleas help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: wixlibs - another feature I have not used.

- [Localizing Extensions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/localized_extensions.html) - that wixlib is probably a localization file.
- [What are .wixlibs and why would you use them?](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/10/10/what-are-.wixlibs-and-why-would-you-use-them/)
- [Create binary .wixlib.](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912047-Create-binary-wixlib-)

---

Bob knows everything about this, but let me chip in with a question in case the problem is something else. Just to verify, can you check all **`*.wxl files`** (localization files) in the project in question? Just to make sure the schema specified is according to what version 4 expects?:

***WiX 4***:

**`English.wxl`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxl">
   <String Id="YOURLOCID">Your localized string</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

***WiX 3***:

**`English.wxl`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="YOURLOCID">Your localized string</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

***Suggestions***:

- So maybe create a localization file (**`*.wxl`**) if it is missing for WiX 4. Either in Visual Studio or slipstream it into your batch build script.
- If there is a **`*.wxl`** there, maybe update the schema to `<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxl">`.
- For command lines, please see this: [How To: Build a Localized Version of Your Installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/build_a_localized_version.html).

Comment: I am afraid I don't use this feature. I suppose you should look in the file **`BrowseDlg.wxs`** to determine what is going on in there as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an Ant task that doesn't support WiX v4. Stick with WiX v3 (the latest supported release).